# R markdown tables to PDF as flexible as htmlTable package

Tags: r, pdf, markdown

is there any development/package you are aware of which would enable (via R markdown) to create tables in a PDF document like those (very flexible!) we are able to create using the htmlTable package for a HTML output?

I am after the ability to combine:

- Multi lines cells (ztable can't do that and it's crucial when you have long text that should fit in a cell)
- Grouping/Sections (pander can't do that)
- Columns and row spans (pander can't do that)
- Rotate column headers (pander can't do that)
- Conditional formatting

I think I tried everything (Pandoc, knitr, kable, xtable, ztable to mentions a few) but one way or another I am always missing one of the elements above (with Pandoc typically being my preferred compromise).

Thanks for help!

As an example consider the following data.frame (which is a reduced version of a much larger table both in terms of rows and columns):

```
scenDes <- data.frame(type = c("Hist", "Stress", "Hist", "Stress"),
                  name = c("Equity Markets Rebound in 2009",
                           "Greece Financial Crisis 2015",
                           "Libya Oil Shock Feb 2011",
                           "Russian Financial Crisis 2008"),
                  description = c("Global equity markets rebound following 2008 drawdown. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "Athens's resistance via referendum and ultimately agreement to rush through long-resisted economic reforms, imposed by its creditors, in a bid to stay in the eurozone. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "Civil war in Libya breaks out on February 15th 2011, causing oil prices to surge. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "War with Georgia and rapidly declining oil prices raise fears of an economic recession within the region. Use Historical risk factor returns."))
```

Using htmlTable I can group the table by "type" and have the "description" as multiline. I didn't manage to find a package which enables me to create a PDF version of that table with those characteristics.
Ideally for other purposes I would like to be able to add spanning columns/rows and add colour/lines for conditional formatting or better visualization on a piece of paper.

In terms of htmlTable this is what I would have done:

```
scenDes <- scenDes[order(scenDes$type),]
acCount <- as.vector(table(scenDes$type))

htmlTable(scenDes[,-1],
            rnames = FALSE,
            align="ll",
            rgroup = unique(scenDes$type),
            n.rgroup = acCount,  
            css.cell = "font-size: 9pt;padding-left:1em; padding-right:2em;")
```

delivering this:
[image]

Maybe not fantastic but, for this specific case, good enough: the crucial bit is to have the wrapping text inside a cell.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example - a small table including all of these features and how you would code it using `htmlTable` - would make this a much better question.

Comment: Quick update: the generic issue of having tables rendered in PDF with the same flexibility you have for the HTML case is still there, in my opinion.
You can add to the mix KableExtra as a package which might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the best I can with `pixiedust`, but it seems I still have some progress to make in the PDF output.

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{arydshln}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{hhline}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r}
scenDes <- data.frame(type = c("Hist", "Stress", "Hist", "Stress"),
                  name = c("Equity Markets Rebound in 2009",
                           "Greece Financial Crisis 2015",
                           "Libya Oil Shock Feb 2011",
                           "Russian Financial Crisis 2008"),
                  description = c("Global equity markets rebound following 2008 drawdown. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "Athens's resistance via referendum and ultimately agreement to rush through long-resisted economic reforms, imposed by its creditors, in a bid to stay in the eurozone. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "Civil war in Libya breaks out on February 15th 2011, causing oil prices to surge. Use Historical risk factor returns.",
                                  "War with Georgia and rapidly declining oil prices raise fears of an economic recession within the region. Use Historical risk factor returns."))
```

```{r}
# devtools::install_github("nutterb/pixiedust", ref = "new-latex-tables")
library(pixiedust)
library(dplyr)

scenDes <- 
  arrange(scenDes, type)

group_row <- 
  lapply(unique(scenDes$type),
         function(x) which(scenDes$type %in% x))

tbl <- 
  scenDes %>%
  arrange(type) %>%
  dust(float = FALSE)

for (i in seq_along(group_row))
{
  tbl <- sprinkle(tbl,
                  cols = "type",
                  rows = group_row[[i]],
                  merge = TRUE)
}

tbl %>%
  sprinkle(cols = "description",
           width = 3.7,
           width_units = "in") %>%
  medley_all_borders(cols = c("name", "description")) %>%
  sprinkle(cols = "type",
           rows = (1:nrow(scenDes))[c(TRUE, FALSE)],
           border = c("top")) %>%
  sprinkle(cols = "type",
           rows = nrow(scenDes),
           border = "bottom") %>%
  medley_bw()
```
````

[image]

Comment: Well, that's something to play with! I wasn't aware of that package. Let me try and revert.